# scan multiple barcode in one textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

For example i got two barcode, so i scan the two barcode at the textbox, it appear AVM12323AVM44454..
But I want it to be displayed in textbox for example like AVM12323, AVM44454. where there is a "," comma between the two code.
Previously i'm only tested for scan one barcode only in the textbox. So now i'm trying to scan more than one barcode in one textbox.
i have been looking the few example but not success.

```
 Private Sub TextBoxMulti_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxMulti.TextChanged
        Dim selectedMultiArrayScan As String()
        Dim selectedMultiScan As String = ""

        selectedMultiScan = TextBoxMulti.Text & ","
        selectedMultiArrayScan = selectedMultiScan.Split(",")

    End Sub

Private Sub MultiScan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MultiScan.Click
    For Each stateName As String In selectedMultiArrayScan
    //some query for each scanned item
    Next stateName
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you test your barcode scanner with `KeyDown` event? Normally scanner will simulate the keyboard input, and send the `Enter` at the end.  But different scanner may different, you may check it with your device.  If that the case, you just need to handle the `KeyDown` event, append the "," after the `Enter` input.

Comment: using the same code in the keydown event?

Comment: What you mean the __same code__? The code you showing just assign the value in variable and do nothing.  You may need to modify your code.

Comment: yes of course it need modify since i facing of problem at here. And i have no clue on what i need to add and modify

Comment: Have you test the `KeyDown` event yet?

Comment: yes.  my scanner didnt  append "," every scanned barcode

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False ' Fire only once
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim <> "" Then TextBox1.Text += ", "
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the textbox with the event TextChanged like this:

```
 If TextBox1.Text.Length >3 Then
        Dim txt As String = Label1.Text + ", " + TextBox1.Text
        If txt.Length = 6 Then txt = txt.Remove(0, 2)
        Label1.Text = txt
        'if you want to erase the text in TextBox1
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0 
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = Label1.Text.Length
        Try
    End If
```

I use this code and it show the Barcodes in a label, you can replace the label to show in the textBox. Also, my Barcodes lenght always have 4 Alphanumeric characters. For you, Replace the `If TextBox1.Text.Length >3 Then` (3 to 8) to detect where a Barcode is readed.